# Kde Konsole swallows Shift-Left and Shift-Right

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, konsole

I'm running `emacs -nw` in console mode inside the KDE `konsole` terminal emulator. In Emacs I have defines Shift-Left and Shift-Right from the `windmove` package to jump horizontally between buffers.
The problem I see is that `konsole` seems to swallow the Shift-Left and Shift-Right keys. The Shift-Up and Shift-Down keys are working. I read the keys received by Emacs with `Ctrl-h l` and can see that no keys are received for Shift-Left and Shift-Right however I get keys for Shift-Up and Shift-Down.

On the other hand I can run Emacs inside `xterm` as well es Emacs inside `gnome-terminal` and receive the right keycodes for Shift-Left and Shift-Right:

```
 ESC [ 1 ; 2 C [windmove-right]
 ESC [ 1 ; 2 D [windmove-left]
```

It seems like KDE `Konsole` is handling the Shift-Left and Shieft-Right keycombinations itself and is not forwarding them. 
I went into `Settings->Edit-CurrentProfile->Keyboard` and edit the `"Default (XFree 4)"` profile. However defining Shift-Left and Shift-Right there doesnt take effect:

```
   Right+Shift \E[1;*C
   Left+Shift  \E[1;*D
```

and test in the "Input" dialog then it seems to yield the right output:

[image]

However if I apply the settings and enter Emacs again I don't receive any characters for Shift-Left and Shift-Right. I also tried adding -AppScreen and +AppScreen but same result.

On the other hand I can see the mapping for Shift+Up and Shift+Down in the  "Default (XFree 4)" profile:

```
   Up+Shift    ScrollLineUp
   Down+Shift  ScrollLineDown
```

These Keycodes reach Emacs in the form of:

```
  ESC [ 1 ; 2 A [windmove-up] 
  ESC [ 1 ; 2 B [windmove-down]
```

Does anyone know why Shift-Left and Shift-Right are handled specially and howto get them work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are also defined as global Konsole shortcuts to switch to the previous/next tab. Go to Konsole's Settings -> Configure Shortcuts and remove them there.

(I performed this first, followed by the step you described. I also had to restart konsole for the changes to take effect; not sure if you'll need to restart too.)

Comment: Or Yakuake shortcuts. On my case, Yakuake was redifining Shift+Left Shift+Right